# ECSlidingViewController passing UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have looked around for solutions but none of them answer my question. Therefore, I took a step back from my project to try to work out this feature. I am using AppDelegate to help me see code clearer.

I want the menu to slide out when users touch and hold the screen. It should slide back when users release their touch.

However, I am unable to send gesture parameters.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
    ScrollViewController *topViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Scroll"];
    MenuViewController *underLeftViewController = (MenuViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];

    ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = [[ECSlidingViewController alloc] initWithTopViewController:topViewController];
    slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = underLeftViewController;

    [slidingViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:slidingViewController.panGesture];
    self.window.rootViewController = slidingViewController;

    // HOW DO I PASS GESTURE DATA?

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *revealMenuRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:slidingViewController.underLeftViewController action:@selector(revealMenu:  GESTURE PARAMETERS?  )];

    [topViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:revealMenuRecognizer];
    return YES;
}
```

**MenuViewController.m**

```
- (void)revealMenu:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressRecognizer {
    if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled
            || longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed
            || longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be `action:@selector(revealMenu:)];` Placing a colon is enough to let the gesture recognizer to pass the UIGestureRecognizer object to the action. Reading from the UIGestureRecognizer reference guide

> The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following
> signatures:
>
> - (void)handleGesture;
> - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
>
> Methods conforming to the latter signature permit the target in some
> cases to query the gesture recognizer sending the message for
> additional information. For example, the target could ask a
> UIRotationGestureRecognizer object for the angle of rotation (in
> radians) since the last invocation of the action method for this
> gesture.

Leave the colon off if you don't care about the object include it if you need data from it. You want the latter.